# referenciar campo generado en procedimiento almacenado sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estoy realizando un procedimiento almacenado, para añadir unos datos a un informe en crystal reports. Estoy realizando lo siguiente:

```
(df.valor_unitario * df.cantidad) as vtotality, /*realiza la operacion y el resultado lo muestra en el campo vtotality */
(select sum(vtotality)) as valor_totalist, /*requiero sumar los valores que toma este campo*/
```

El campo que recibe los valores, no existe en ninguna tabla de la base de datos, solo en el procedimiento almacenado, pero no he logrado referenciarlo de forma que se puedan sumar los valores que toma.

lo presente es para sumar los precios de varios artículos y generar un total

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que no estas hablando de un campo sino de una variable dentro del procedimiento almacenado, por lo que lo primero es declararla, toda variable de define con el `@` al comienzo del nombre y deberemos indicar el tipo de dato. Lo siguiente, si lo que buscas es guardar en ella el valor producto de la suma de ciertas columnas de una consulta, es hacer esto:

```
DECLARE @vtotality NUMERIC(15,2)

SELECT @vtotality = SUM(valor_unitario * cantidad) 
       FROM tu_tabla 
       where ariculo in ('Art1', 'Art2')

SELECT  @vtotality
```

Una vez declarada, `@vtotality` puede usarse como parte de cualquier `SELECT` incluso de una consulta con alguna otra tabla.

Comment: lo que se debe sumar es la variable @vtotality en este caso ella almacenaria un valor por articulo, supongamos que tengo dos articulos cuyos valores son: Art1= 500.000 art2= 300.000, lo que deseo hacer es que con la variable vtotality se sumen estos dos para tener un total de 800.000

Comment: @SalomMaurno, Si la información sale de la misma tabla, podrías hacer algo así: `SELECT  @vtotality = SUM(valor_unitario * cantidad)        FROM tu_tabla where ariculo in ('Art1', 'Art2')`, Si sale de dos consultas realmente distintas, puedes crear dos variables intermedias para cada valor y por último haces `SET @vtotality = @Valor1 + @Valor2`

Comment: Pueden salir *n* cantidad de articulos, el numero lo desconozco. Por lo tanto no me serviría definir una consulta por articulo, ya que requiero sumar todos los que salgan

Comment: esta tiende a ser una consulta independiente de lo que quiero, ya que ella hace una operación diferente, lo que debo sumar son los resultados de esa operación, que se realiza para cada uno de los articulos `(df.valor_unitario * df.cantidad) as vtotality,`

Comment: @SalomMaurno, si son operaciones diferentes, por ejemplo dentro de un cursor estás haciendo varios `select` lo que puedes hacer es ir acumulando la variable mediante algo así: `SELECT @vtotality = @vtotality + (valor_unitario * cantidad) FROM ....`, obviamente antes que nada debieras hacer `SET @vtotality = 0`

Comment: quiero tener esos valores en campos independientes

Comment: A ver.. una variable solo puede contener un valor, si necesitas más valores, necesitas declarar más variables, pero me dices que no sabes la cantidad, por consiguiente usar variables no es la solución. Resumiendo, evidentemente no entendí tu problema.

Comment: si eso es claro, solo es posible contener un valor. lo Resumo de la siguiente forma: 1. (df.valor_unitario * df.cantidad) as vtotality hago la anterior operacion cuyo resultado lo almaceno en un campo llamado vtotality aun no se define la variable, esto se procede a realizar para cada articulo que salga, supongamos que salieron *n* cantidad de articulos, la idea es que se sumen y se muestren la suma de esta operacion este en otro campo.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GLAJB6 le comparto el codigo, quizas asi me puede dar un ejemplo mas claro. ya que como dices me ha de generar error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76526/discussion-between-salom-maurno-and-patricio-moracho).